# What is a technical term for a model that takes as input the output of multiple other models?

Tags: terminology, model

I have 60+ models (could be basic if-else rules or complex neural networks) that describe population risk. Each of the models has at least one output (often more). What is the technical term for the **top-level** model that summarises every risk by taking the 60+ model outputs as inputs? I don't want a name for the whole process ;)

I'm thinking 'summary' or 'integrated' model, but if there's an already existing term, that would be great.

Comment: ensemble would be my guess

Comment: @probabilityislogic Yess perfect - thanks for that. I'll accept that if you make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term for such techniques is ensemble learning as suggested by @probabilityislogic.  Specifically, if the level-1 model is also trained, it would be an example of [Stacking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking).